# Forcing a minimum number of unique variables per solution with PuLP

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I'm using the PuLP library in python to build daily fantasy sports lineups for PGA. The inputs and constraints are fairly simple, and the problem is working perfectly. The code is as follows:

```py
# There will be an index for each player and the variable will be binary (0 or 1) representing whether the player is included or excluded from the roster.
# player_dict is a dictionary of each player, containing data like Name, Fpts, Salary, etc...
lp_variables = {
    player: plp.LpVariable(player, cat="Binary")
    for player, _ in self.player_dict.items()
}

# set the objective - maximize fpts
self.problem += (
    plp.lpSum(
        self.player_dict[player]["Fpts"] * lp_variables[player]
        for player in self.player_dict
    ),
    "Objective",
)

# Set the salary constraints
max_salary = 50000 if self.site == "dk" else 60000
min_salary = 0

self.problem += (
    plp.lpSum(
        self.player_dict[player]["Salary"] * lp_variables[player]
        for player in self.player_dict
    )
    <= max_salary
)
self.problem += (
    plp.lpSum(
        self.player_dict[player]["Salary"] * lp_variables[player]
        for player in self.player_dict
    )
    >= self.min_salary
)

# Need 6 golfers regardless of site. pretty easy.
self.problem += (
    plp.lpSum(lp_variables[player] for player in self.player_dict) >= 6
)
self.problem += (
    plp.lpSum(lp_variables[player] for player in self.player_dict) <= 6
)

# Crunch!
for i in range(self.num_lineups):
    try:
        self.problem.solve(plp.PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=0))
    except plp.PulpSolverError:
        self.simDoc.update({'jobProgressLog': ArrayUnion(['There was an error with the solver - infeasibility reached. Only generated {} lineups out of {}. Continuing with export.'.format(len(self.num_lineups), self.num_lineups)])})
       
    score = str(self.problem.objective)
    for v in self.problem.variables():
        score = score.replace(v.name, str(v.varValue))
        
    player_names = [
        v.name.replace("_", " ")
        for v in self.problem.variables()
        if v.varValue != 0
    ]
    fpts = eval(score)

    self.lineups[fpts] = player_names
    
    # Force new optimal solution
    self.problem += plp.lpSum(
        self.player_dict[player]["Fpts"] * lp_variables[player]
        for player in self.player_dict
    ) <= (fpts - 0.001)
```

However, I want to add an additional optional constraint that forces each solution to have a minimum number of unique players from one another.

For example, if I were to force a minimum number of 3 unique players per lineup, the following lineups would be invalid, since they are only unique by 2 variables.

```
[Player1, Player4, Player29, Player6, Player10]
[Player1, Player4, Player29, Player88, Player45]
```

How can I go about implementing this rule using PuLP to enforce that each subsequent lineup produced has at least 3 unique players from the lineups before it?

Comment: Non-reproducible; you haven't given us `self` and its members. The program needs to run top-to-bottom when copied and pasted from this page.

Comment: Also, `eval(score)` is cursed. PuLP has functions for this.

Comment: @Reinderien what should be preferred then? Is there a noticeable performance hit from using eval(score)?

Comment: It's not (only) about performance; it's about code quality, security, maintainability, etc. There is such a long list of reasons not to do this, and the proper way to do this is so easy in comparison.